# Cannot upload media via Wordpress uploader

Tags: wordpress, upload, permissions

This has to do with media uploading in Wordpress.

Every time WP creates a folder for new uploads (it organizes uploads by year and month: yyyy/mm), it creates it with the "apache:apache' user and group, with full access to all (777 or `drwxrwxrwx`).

However, after that, WP cannot create a folder within that folder (e.g.: mkdir `2011` succeeds, but mkdir `2011/01` fails).  Also, uploads cannot be moved into these newly created folders even though the permissions are 777 (`rwxrwxrwx`).

Once a month, I have to `chown` the newly created folders to be the same as user:group as the rest of the files. Once I do that, uploading works fine (which doesn't make sense to me The really frustrating part is that this problem doesn't exist in other WP installs on other domains on the same server.

* I wasn't sure if this should be here or on serverfault.

---

Edit: The containing directory `/.../httpdocs/blog/wp-content/uploads` has the correct ownership

```
drwxrwxrwx 5 myuser psaserv 4096 Jun  3 18:38 uploads
```

This is a Plesk/CentOS environment hosted by Media Temple (dv).

I've written the following test script to simulate the problem

```
<pre><?php 

$d = "d" . mt_rand(100, 500);

var_dump(
    get_current_user(),
    $d,
    mkdir($d),
    chmod($d, 0777),
    mkdir("$d/$d"),
    chmod("$d/$d", 0777),
    fileowner($d),
    getmyuid()
);
```

The script always creates the first directory `mkdir($d)` successfully. On domain A, where the WP problem is, it cannot create the nested directory `mkdir("$d/$d")`.  However, on domain B, both directories are successfully created.

I am running each script at `/var/www/vhosts/domainA/httpdocs/tmp/t.php` and `/var/www/vhosts/domainB/httpdocs/tmp/t.php` respectively  I checked the permissions on `tmp`, `httpdocs`, and `domain[AB]` and they are the same for each path.  The only thing that differs is the user.

Comment: I had this problem once with WordPress on a Plesk server, never figured out how to fix it and ended moving it to another host.

Comment: Damn, I'm in the same boat.  That's not very promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to your miscellaneous settings page (or media depending on your version) and make sure the upload directory is still wp-content/uploads.

If you need to. set the full url too.

Also, as a final solution, disable the option to organize them into folders so that way WordPress doesn't even need to create folders.

Comment: Your final solution does work, however, it doesn't address the underlying problem :(  If I don't get an answer to that effect, I'll definitely award you the bounty.  As a side question, what host did you have this problem on?

Comment: Some random small shop for a client. I had to wrestle with issue after issue with the host until I finally convinced the client to move to my host after 2 years. Oddly, there just haven't been as many issues since then.

It is probably a PHP safe mode thing. I did some googling, and saw a couple recommendations to set the owners to `nobody`. This thread has a bunch of posts about it: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/254069

Comment: Oh, I assume you tried this, but have you recursively explicitly set the scripts and the folders to the same owner?

Comment: Yes I have.  PHP is running as apache:apache and creates the folders with the same ownership.  The problem is that even though the permissions are `rwxrwxrwx`, PHP cannot move uploaded files inside of the folder it has just created.  There's something screwed up with the permissions along the way in some parent folder for this specific domain, but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to use FastCgi. This makes PHP run as the user who owns the site. New files and folders will be the same user and group. This will solve your problem.

There is a performance penalty to FastCgi but you get some added security as it restricts php. If you are hosting multiple website with multiple users this could be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Check for a setuid or setgid bit on a directory above the 2010 directory.  ls -l will have an s or S in the permissions for the directory.  Make sure this directory has the correct ownership.

Comment: I tried my sample script with and without `s` set on the containing `tmp` directory, but I was unable to create the nested folder (see my edit).

Comment: Are the directories being created as the same user on both domains? Compare the directory tree all the way to /.  There could be a permission problem further up the tree.

Comment: I compared the directory tree all the way up to `/var/www/vhosts` where both domains are located. As far as I could tell, they were identical permissions.  The only thing that differed between the two paths were the user.  The group is the same for both paths (psaserv), but each domain has a different user (a restriction of Plesk).

Answer (score 1):

Try to create directory recursive with `mkdir($d, true)`

```
<pre><?php 

$d = "d" . mt_rand(100, 500);

var_dump(
         array(
               get_current_user(),
               $d,
               mkdir($d,true),
               chmod($d, 0777),
               mkdir("$d/$d", true),
               chmod("$d/$d", 0777),
               fileowner($d),
               getmyuid()
              )
        );
```

Comment: I tried it, but it makes no difference. Also, this is not how WP creates directories (for uploads at least) and I don't want to fork the codebase for something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Joomla recently, and solved the problem by adding myuser into the apache group, and add apache into the psaserv group.

Answer (score 1):

One of our websites on a Media Temple DV was having this problem. Turning PHP Safe Mode off solved it.  The directories were still created as apache:apache, but the media files were allowed in there.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that occurred to me - WP will tell you that it can nto copy file to `/wp-content/upload` even when all permissions are right.... if

> `upload_max_filesize`

in `php.ini` is too small (say 2M and you try to upload 3.5MB file)!

Hope that helps all thsoe who have right permissions but still can not upload!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need 777 on your directories, 775 at most should be sufficient. Just make sure it's set on the uploads directory with 755 for all the other directories above.

Also, you could try to chown it to www-data, sometimes that helps when your ftp user that you are logged in as when changing the permissions once a month doesn't have sufficient access level and owning the directories by that user prevents the server from being able to write into them.

Lastly, as someone has pointed out above, you may need to up the upload size limit along with making sure other file upload related php.ini settings are correct:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/137/How+can+I+edit+the+php.ini+file%3F#dv

Answer (score 1):

One common cause, often overlooked, is the disk quota, ie have you run out of disk space.